# How to get result for each element in array using PDO::fetchAll()?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have an array with id's and I want to get result for each id from pgsql db. But I dont want to make multiple requests like

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $result[$a] = $pdo->add('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ' . $a)->execute()->fetchAll();
}
```

I want something like

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$pl = '(' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?')) . ')';
$result = $pdo->add('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ' . $pl)->execute($array)->fetchAll();
```

But the problem is, if there are 10 id but only 7 records from request, I cannot determine which records belong to which id.

I want to make one request to db and get results like this, is there any options?

```
$data = [
    ['id' = 1, 'ok' = 1],
    ['id' = 2, 'ok' = 1],        
    ['id' = 3, 'ok' = 0],
    ['id' = 4, 'ok' = 0],
    ['id' = 5, 'ok' = 1],
]
$keys = [1,2,3,4,5];
$res = $pdo->add('SELECT id FROM table WHERE ok = 1')->execute()->fetchAll();

//Result
$res = array(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => null
    [4] => null
    [5] => 5
)
```

Comment: Well, each row has an `id` field, telling you which id it has…‽

Comment: By the way, you cannot chain fetchAll() to execute() like this. execute doesn't return the statement

Comment: as of your question, the closest solution I can offer is [PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE) which will index the resulting array with id, and then you can simply foreach($array as $id) $row = $result[$id] ?? null;

Comment: where do these ids come from?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have array of ids like ['qwe1', 'erd4', 'ffe4'] and so on, i have like 50k ids

Comment: But where do they come from?

Comment: @YourCommonSense they come from another select request (the code is too complicated and i dont think that anyone will understand it without seeing the table, and i cannot provide it).

Comment: so you just use a left join in that other select and get the exact outcome you need.